# AZP: Is there a best practice to be able to "namespace" script tasks in yaml templates for usage of variables?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure Pipelines: my main problem is, if I create a yml template and have some logic inside that template in a script task where I want to set a variable, i need the

`name: "pseudonamespace"` to reference that variable further down in that template via

`$(pseudonamespace.variablename)`

An example, where the script part does nothing overtly useful, but should demonstrate my problem:

mytemplate.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: isWindowsOnTarget
  type: boolean
  default: true

steps:
- script: |
    if [ "${{lower(parameters.isWindowsOnTarget)}}" == "true" ]; then
      delimiter="\\"
    else
      delimiter="/"
    fi
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myCoolVariable;isOutput=true]$delimiter"
  name: MyFakeNameSpace

...
- task: SomeTask@0
  inputs:
    myInput: $(MyFakeNameSpace.myCoolVariable)
```

This codeblock works; but only, if, in a job, I only instanciate it once:

```
- template: mytemplate.yml@templates
   parameters:
     isWindowsOnTarget: true
```

If I would need that template twice, differently parameterized, I get the error that the name of the script block needs to be unique.

Is there any useful possibility I'm not currently thinking about other than to have an extra parameter for the template that I could basically just call "UniqueNamespace"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no much space to move. Your task needs a unique name as later as you mention for output parameters it works like a namespace. So the best and the only way you have is to provide another parameter which would be task name.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: isWindowsOnTarget
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: taskName
  type: string

steps:
- script: |
    if [ "${{lower(parameters.isWindowsOnTarget)}}" == "true" ]; then
      delimiter="\\"
    else
      delimiter="/"
    fi
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myCoolVariable;isOutput=true]$delimiter"
  name: ${{ parameters.taskName }}

...
- task: SomeTask@0
  inputs:
    myInput: $(MyFakeNameSpace.myCoolVariable)
```

and then:

```yaml
- template: mytemplate.yml@templates
   parameters:
     isWindowsOnTarget: true
     taskName: MyFakeNameSpace
- template: mytemplate.yml@templates
   parameters:
     isWindowsOnTarget: true
     taskName: MyFakeNameSpace2
```

In fact when you do not provide a name Azure DevOps assign a unique name. However, in this way you don't know the name till runtime.